# Magento OnePage Success Blank Content

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've got Onepage and Goodcheckout enabled

I've copied the success.phtml to my active theme folder but it's showing blank success page content. I can see the header but the rest of the page is blank

I activated debug but no errors showing, why would the succcess.phtml not show correctly while using this extension?

You can test by going here -https://www.premiumpetfoodonline.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=test1-2kg 
Checkout and you'll see the success page

Comment: Ah it was this bit of code causing the blank page.

      <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
     <h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your 
       purchase!') ?></h2>

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code at the top of the success.phtml had been altered, I removed the title call and block request as it isn't needed as header is already set

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></h2>
```